# Joining diagonal divs with flex

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have 2 divs. Right div is an image cutted diagonally. Left divs must have some text inside. I want this to be fully responsive like this:

[image: fullscreen]

The problem occurs when I change window size, it's collapsing like in the image:

[image: sized down].

Also there is a text on left div that need to be displayed, but with flex this seems not to work so i disabled it. Please provide solution for this. 
Here is my css and html:

```css
#diagonal {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
#diagonal #ct-about-col-left {
  width: 60%;
  border-right: 190px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 500px solid grey;
  z-index: 2;
}
#diagonal span {
  display: none;
}
#ct-about-col-right {
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
  background-image: url(images/content/about/right-col-image.jpg);
  z-index: 0;
  margin-left: -12%;
  margin-right: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="diagonal">
  <div id="ct-about-col-left">
    <span>We are the best</span>
    <span>text1 text1 text1</span>
    <span>Text2 text2 text2 text2</span>
    <div>
      <span>Read more</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ct-about-col-right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest another approach which will save You some markup space and CSS rules as well.

Simply create a full-width div with the ID of lets say `ct-about`, give it a background color `grey` and then simply chain the image background on top of the color like so:

```
background: url('images/content/about/right-col-image.jpg') no-repeat right top, grey;
```

This simply tells the browser, make my box grey and put that image over the grey color. The `no-repeat right top` properties are preventing the browser from repeating the image so you don't get a tile, tell ti to place the image on the far right and top positions.

This way everything will be responsive as well.

> Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6fdujf1/1/)** for You to better understand.
>
> You can find more information about multiple CSS backgrounds in the **[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)**

Comment: This is actually what i've been lookin. Only thing I should do myself is to apply transparent background to this triangle image fragment. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. In all types of programming, always aim for the most lean approach there is.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe consider a slightly different mark-up and method of adding the picture (as a background-image) and making the angle (with transform: skew).

Live Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjyKRo

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="caption">
    <p>CONTENT</p>
  </div>
</div>


* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;

  overflow: hidden;

  background-image: url("http://unsplash.it/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 50%;
}

.caption {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 500px;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-left: 130px;
  background-color: #ddd;

  transform: skew(10deg, 0deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%; 
}

.caption p {

  transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
}
```

Comment: this looks promising to what i want to achieve but in your code the text inside p tag isn't showing. I want text to be visible on left div.

Comment: the problem is the `padding-top: 20%` rule is forcing the `p` down too much - this is calculated relative to *width* - but since `top` is not, it's an easy fix:  change this to `padding-top:10px; top: 20%;` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pReZmM